# How to keep console app running while waiting for WCF callback?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm writing a program that receives implements callback from 3rd party service. I'm currently keeping the app open through `Console.ReadLine`, however, I'm not sure if it's freezing the whole program while waiting for input from user? Or my callbacks doesn't work.

Please bear with me, first time using .net; Got most of the code, specially the callbackevents thing on the third party api documentation.

Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
   var callback = new ThirdPartyCallbackImplementation();
   var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
   ThirdPartyClient client = new ThirdPartyClient(context);

   callback.FoundEvent += CallbackOnFoundEvent;
   client.Subscribe();

   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void CallbackOnFoundEvent(object info) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Something was found!");
}
```

ThirdPartyCallbackImplementation:

```
public delegate void CallBackEvent(object info);

[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false, ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]

public class ThirdPartyCallbackImplementation : ThirdPartyCallback
{
   public event CallBackEvent FoundEvent;

   private void OnFound(object info)
   {
      this.FoundEvent?.Invoke(info);
   }

   // function implementation
   public void Found()
   {
      CallBackEvent c = this.OnFound;
      c.BeginInvoke(result, ar => { }, null);
   }
}
```

There's no error at all. It just there saying `Hello World!`. API was surely working as it has its own interface and it triggering properly.

Comment: Im not really sure, but it seems to me that `OnFound` and `Found` functions are just calling each other?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to register a handler for the `FoundEvent` ? Are you getting the "Something was found!" output? And I am missing somehow where you trigger the Service to actually find something.

Comment: and where are you calling WCF service? Is this a whole code?

Comment: And where are you pulling `result` from? Please consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: _I'm not sure if it's freezing the whole program while waiting for input from user_. No, it blocks only your current thread.

Comment: @VladaxLe so that means anything comes from callback should fire, WriteLine perhaps?

Comment: @Selvin I have updated the code, I was missing the WCF call the whole time.

Comment: Your callback seems unnecessarily complicated. Why don't you just fire FoundEvent within Found()? As for your problem, the first step would be to put a breakpoint in Found() and see if it triggers.

Comment: 1. Where is the WCF call in your example? 2. How exactly your subscriptions work? 3. Calls are synchronous by default in WCF so it means that your thread will be blocked anyway. If the call is done asynchronously then you can wait on IAsyncResult

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to leverage the Rx Event Extensions

```
public async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var callback = new ThirdPartyCallbackImplementation();
   var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
   ThirdPartyClient client = new ThirdPartyClient(context);


   client.Subscribe();
   object info = await callback.WhenEventFound()
                      //timeout
                      .Take(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                      .ToTask();
   if(info != null)
      Console.WriteLine("Something was found!");

   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IObservable<object> WhenEventFound(this ThirdPartyCallbackImplementation proxy)
{
     return Observable.FromEvent<CallBackEvent, object>(h => x => h(x),
            handler => proxy.FoundEvent += handler,
            handler => proxy.FoundEvent -= handler)
}
```

This code looks very much like a library which has been ported from Java, possibly Ignite.net.